# Always position next & prev top

Tags: html, css, position

Stackoverflow I am trying to position the "next" and "prev" arrows always at top of the sidebar (sidebar header), however can't figure out how to get the same position both on desktop and mobile devices?

existing code:

```css
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 16px;
}

.next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: white;
}

.sidebar {
  display: inherit;
  grid-gap: inherit;
}

@media (min-width: 67.5em) and (max-width: 40em) {
  .sidebar {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    0
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 1353px) {
  .Gridcontainer {
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 1352px) {
  .sidebar {
    grid-auto-rows: 100%;
    grid-row: span 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="Gridcontainer">
  <div class="Intro">
    <video autoplay="" class="Videohack" loop="">
      <source src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a> <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question, where is this sidebar positioned in relation to the content?

Comment: The sidebar is placed on the lefthand-side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define `top` for both buttons, for example `50%`:

```css
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;         /* this makes the difference */
  ...
```

**Working example:** (*i added for demonstration another color for the buttons*)

```css
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;         /* this makes the difference */
  padding: 16px;
  color: gray;      /* just for demonstration */
}

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: white;
}

.sidebar {
  display: inherit;
  grid-gap: inherit;
}

@media (min-width: 67.5em) and (max-width: 40em) {
  .sidebar {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    0
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 1353px) {
  .Gridcontainer {
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 1352px) {
  .sidebar {
    grid-auto-rows: 100%;
    grid-row: span 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="Gridcontainer">
  <div class="Intro">
    <video autoplay="" class="Videohack" loop="">
      <source src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a> <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>
  </div>
</div>
```